# Nested divs display on hover menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a JSFiddle, please view.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/king2525/9965yanr/1/)

I am having trouble targeting css on hover function for nested div. In the code example, how I can have the following target a specific div

```
div id=”nav1″ display div id=”section5″

div id=”nav2″ display div id=”section6″
```

Currently, `parent div id=”nav” displays div id=”section5″`

If there is a better method, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any javascript, or jquery. Jquery has a hover event https://api.jquery.com/hover/ that may help you do what you want better than pure css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your HTML structure a little, removing the parent `.nav` to make `#nav1`, `#nav2`, `#section5` and `#section6` "siblings". Then use the siblings CSS selector to target what you want:

**CSS:**

```
#nav1:hover ~ #section5,
    #section5:hover  {
    display:  block;
}

#nav2:hover ~ #section6,
    #section6:hover  {
    display:  block;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/9965yanr/6/

**EDIT:**

Add `float` and anothers properties that `.nav` had, with some adjusments that you can improve. See the working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/9965yanr/8/

Comment: Thank you Imgonzalves. I appreciate it. How can I have the content appear to the right of the menu, like in my example?

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. I made an update. Please see updated fiddle. The S6 Edge image bleeds into the menu column, how can I have the content on the right side of the gray line? Can the image positioned right of the S6 Edge info text and links, similar to like another column. https://jsfiddle.net/king2525/2f1z4uhm/4/

Comment: Apply clear: left and margin-left: 150px to the sections. See https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2f1z4uhm/6/

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Instead of having one column, as it is now, how can we have 2 columns for all of the div "sections" i.e div id="section5" ?

Comment: @Elvis I think that I already answer your main question. If you need add more requirements, add another question and I will help you with your new needs. Please accept the answer and open a new one :)